# How to trim whitespace from the end of a multi-line string?

Tags: whitespace

It seems subr-x's `string-trim-right` only operates on the last line.

How to strip trailing spaces on all lines in a variable?

Comment: ITYM it operates on a string, not lines inside a string. By that definition it does indeed "trim whitespace from the end of a multi-line string". I'd be surprised if it trimmed it in the middle of it, just because there happened to be a newline at that place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by splitting and joining strings:

```elisp
(require 'subr-x)
(defun string-trim-right-multiline (str)
  (mapconcat 'string-trim-right
   (split-string str "\n") "\n"))
```

---

Note that if you want to perform other operations on the string you can define a function:

```elisp
(require 'subr-x)
(defun string-trim-right-multiline (str)
  (mapconcat (function (lambda (s) (string-trim-right s)))
   (split-string str "\n") "\n"))
```

Comment: You can replace `(function (lambda (s) (string-trim-right s)))` with just `'string-trim-right`.

Comment: Done, but included previous since it can be handy to make other edits.